# Completion handler for property in swift

Tags: objective-c, ios8, completionhandler

I'm trying to use a control called MZFormSheetController in swift. In the example given it provides a property as a completion handler, if I understand correctly, but I'm having difficulties translating it in Swift. Any help would be appreciated.

This is in the obj-c example.

```
controller.didPresentContentViewControllerHandler = ^(UIViewController *content) {
    NSLog(@"DID PRESENT");
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
};
```

I tried many variations and did an extensive search in the web but I could not find anything that could help me so I'm stuck here

```
controller.didPresentContentViewControllerHandler = (content:UIViewController() -> () {
    println("did present1")
})
```

Here are the relevant docs: [Cocoa Docs:: MZFormSheetPresentationController:: didPresentContentViewControllerHandler](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MZFormSheetController/3.0.0/Classes/MZFormSheetPresentationController.html#//api/name/didPresentContentViewControllerHandler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add a variable after opening brace

```
controller.didPresentContentViewControllerHandler = {
    vc in
    println("did present1")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access the view controller then do it like this,

```
controller.didPresentContentViewControllerHandler = {
    controller in
    println("did present1")
}
```

Or if you dont need the reference to the view controller, you can simply do,

```
let controller = Controller()
controller.didPresentContentViewControllerHandler = {
    _ in
     println("did present1")
}
```